# Wordpress "Page not found error" when I edit a page

Tags: html, 404-error, visual-editor

On a Wordpress based website, when I add text using wordpress visual editor or HTML source to a particular page - it gives "page not found error". I tried by adding some other text and its working fine. Then I typed all the text again and in between kept checking if it is giving any errors. Finally I am able to point to the exact word that is causing problem - from. If I put frm , rom or from it works. Only when I use "from" - it gives page not found error. Another thing, the error is only this page not on any other page. I have used "from" on many other pages and there is no problem at all.

Its a client website and I do not have access to the server. I only have wordpress login/password. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I even tried HTML entities and it does not work. Right now we are using "fróm" instead of "from" as a workaround.

Comment: You're getting a 404 if your page content contains the word `from`?

Comment: @polarblau: Yes

Comment: @Keoki Zee: let me know more details you require. Your suggestion about posting to WordPress Answers is great. Can I migrate the question there since it is purely related to WordPress.

Comment: That sure is a good one. Could you post some of the code in question?

Comment: @polarblau : It is just some content given by the client.. no matter what the other content is, it just do not accept "from". The moment you put from and view preview or publish the page, the page is gone. I think it is some bug in WordPress. Another relevant information is the we are using 'pretty urls' .

Comment: It's impossible to tell what causes this issue without seeing the code that prints the content on the page, since any WP site I've been working on so far did allow the usage of the word 'from'.

Comment: @polarblau : yes, it is strange for me too; and all other pages of the website allow "from" as well. I am not sure whats causing the issue. I even deleted and created the page again and no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What form are your pretty permalinks taking, and what is the title of that page? I've had something similar happen and it had to do with the page title. Try flushing your permalinks (go to Settings > Permalinks and switch to a different default, save, then switch back again to what you were using).

Though of course this doesn't explain at all why putting the word 'from' in the body of the post would make any difference at all. :(

Answer (score 3):

Just had exactly weird "from" word issue on a single post, and traced it to Wordpress SEO plugin by Yoast. It may be a sum of other causes for sure, as this got away so far up to this versions.
Using the latest versions by now:

- Wordpress SEO plugin by Yoast, Version 1.6.3
- Wordpress 4.0

Deactivating Wordpress SEO plugin, instantly allowed me to edit the post again, the post in which I had just added the word "from", two times, in the last edit.

Flushing the permalinks, or changing the post slug did nothing in my case. 
Anyway, as long as the Edit page url is like: `/wp-admin/post.php?post=4076&action=edit`,
I don't see why permalinks would matter..

I would hint that there is a bug in the way Wordpress SEO plugin does the text analysis to gather keyword calculations.

UPDATE: 
- removing the "from" word in the post did not solve the not found error, but disabling Wordpress SEO does.. so there may be other words or other related issues!
- MODSEC_ENABLE solution causes 500 Internal server error

Answer (score 2):

Found this solution in Wordpress.org site
you need to add this line into your `.htaccess` file.

```
# BEGIN 404 Fix

< IfModule mod_env.c >
SetEnv MODSEC_ENABLE Off
PassEnv MODSEC_ENABLE
< /IfModule >

#END 404 Fix
```

Hope this will help out your problem

Answer (score 0):

It's very late to write answers, but it's working, I have also faced same problem many times, There is no relation between permalink and post how ever its work if you switch it to default permalink but it was blocked by **Mod Security**

Know issue reasons:

1. Custom Permalink
2. Mode Security Enabled on server

Solution:

1. Check mode security log to find Blocking plugin and disable plugin Or Disable same rule on Mode security.
2. Switch to Normal Permalink (Only Work in some conditions like some plugins load by permalink on back end)
3. Check by disabling plugins one by one and test every time you may got issue creating plugin.